# mapping sql row values to column names

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am using rowset to import excel data into sql 2008

The column names end up being F1,F2,F3 etc etc.

The first row of data however contains the values that should actually be the column names.

For example,

```
F1         F2           F3              F4
---------------------------------------------------
BoxName    BoxDesc      Entity          EntityDesc
```

I want to rename the columns to the values of the first row, so column F1 becomes BoxName, F2 becomes BoxDesc.

Additionally, I want to be able to do this even if the order of columns change and by using a variable as the table name OR if the number of columns change OR if the column names change.

Your help appreciated.

thanks,

KS

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the [sp_executesql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) stored procedure, I think it can solve your problem. After import of excel file into the temporary table temp select the row with the column names, the 4th row in this case:

```
DECLARE @F1Col AS VARCHAR(50), @F2Col AS VARCHAR(50), @F3Col AS VARCHAR(50), @F4Col AS VARCHAR(50)


    SELECT TOP 4 @F1Col = F1,
    @F2Col = F2,
    @F3Col = F3,
    @F4Col = F4
    FROM temp

    SELECT F1 AS @F1Col,
    F2 AS @F2Col, 
    F3 AS @F3Col, 
    F4 AS @F4Col
    EXCEPT
    SELECT TOP 4 F1 AS @F1Col,
    F2 AS @F2Col,
    F3 AS @F3Col,
    F4 AS @F4Col
    FROM temp
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have stated that the excel file has some extra rows before the row where the actual column name values are.
I use HDR=NO, and then in sql I remove the extra rows, thus ending up with the column name value rows in the first row (if that makes sense).

Answer (score 0):

I used the dynamic sql approach in the end using sp_executeSql.

First I got the max no of columns that i needed.

Then I used a while loop to iterate through the columns renaming the headers.

```
--Get the column name from the 4th row and store in @NewName, actual col name is F{n}
WHILE (@Counter < @MaxCols+1)
BEGIN
    Set @RowColVal = 'F'+RTrim(@Counter)
    Set @tmpSQL = N'SELECT @NewName = ' + @RowColVal + ' from MyTable WHERE ID=4'
EXEC sp_executesql @tmpSQL, N'@NewName nvarchar(50) OUTPUT', @NewName=@NewColName OUTPUT
Set @RenameTargetCol1 = 'MyTable.'+@RowColVal

    --rename column
    EXEC sp_RENAME @RenameTargetCol1, @NewColName, 'COLUMN'

    Set @Counter = @Counter+1
END
```